# DT Package Column Filters Not Working in RMarkdown HTML

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, dt

I am using RMarkdown and the DT package to create dynamic tables in an HTML report. I am trying to add in column filters by adding in [filter = 'top'] as outlined in the DT package documentation so the user can search each column individually. However, when I knit to HTML the column level filters are there but they do not work. I am using the latest version of R Studio and version 0.4 of the DT package. What am I doing wrong?

````
 ---
 title: <b>Report</b>
 date: Updated `r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`
 output:
 rmarkdown::html_document:
 theme: cosmo
---

 ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
 knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
 library(rmarkdown)
 library(DT)
 library(htmltools)
 library(knitr)
 ```

 ###Tab 1: Alphabetic List of Fields

```{r by.field, echo=FALSE,results="asis",warning=FALSE}

#Making the table
fieldname=binned_data$Attribute.from.EHR.database
field_def=binned_data$Definition
field_table=binned_data$Table
fieldtable=data.frame(fieldname, field_def, field_table)


print(htmltools::tagList(
datatable(
fieldtable, colnames=c(
  "Field","Definition", "Table"), 
    filter = 'top',
    options = list(autowidth = TRUE,
    order = list(list(0, 'asc')),
    columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-left', targets = c(0,1,2))),
      pageLength = 25, 
      lengthMenu = c(25, 50, 75, 100, 150),
      initComplete = JS("
        function(settings, json) {
        ","
        $('body').css({
        'font-family': 'Century Gothic', 'font-size': '150%'
        });
        $(this.api().table().header()).css({
        'font-family': 'Century Gothic',
        'font-size':'125%',
        'background-color': '#008000',
        'color': '#fff'
        });
        }
        ")
),rownames = FALSE
)))

```
````

This is what the output looks like, but when I start typing in the column filter box nothing happens.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Sseb.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I'm **very** **new** to R, so I'm not sure of the root of your issue, but I experienced this same problem recently. After I formatted my numeric columns using `df$var <- currency(df$var, digits = 0L)`, I wasn't able to filter any of my datatable columns in my rmd html output. (And the formatting also didn't show up in the datatable... womp.)

I got rid of the currency format and then the filters worked just fine.

So it possibly could be that some formatting of your variable values is causing the filter to fail. (Although it seems a bummer to not be able to format values and also filter, but again, I'm new, and could be doing it wrong...) I wish I could help you identify the *possible* formatting culprit... but maybe this will be a start.

(Also check out the red box in [this link](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html), which lists known issues with DT extensions and column filters.)

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove `autoWidth = TRUE` from my DT options in order for filtering to work in my Rmarkdown HTML file.